# not showing MotionEvent.ACTION_UP or MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL

Tags: java, android, touch

I am writing an Android app that needs to respond to touch events. I want my app to change the color of my list item to a custom color. I have written the following code, but only the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` section is working. The LogCat shows that `ACTION_CANCEL` and `ACTION_UP` aren't called at all. Could you please help me understand why my code isn't working.

This is my code...

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(1, 1, 1));
            Log.d("onTouch", "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP" );
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(23, 128, 0));
            Log.d("onTouch", "MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN" );
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(1, 1, 1));
            Log.d("onTouch", "MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL" );
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you put a Log as the first line of the method (before the first `if` statement). Is the method getting triggered at all the times that you expect it to? Also, if you're moving, possibly the events are getting *batched*, as described in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you return `false` from `onTouch` method, no further events get delivered to the listener. You should return `true` at least in case of `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`.

Refactor your code as given below:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(1, 1, 1));
    Log.d("onTouch", "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP" );
}
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(23, 128, 0));
    Log.d("onTouch", "MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN" );
    return true;
}

if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(1, 1, 1));
    Log.d("onTouch", "MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL" );
}
return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh, i am aslo having same issue with same kind of code. its not working for me even if i return true. and if i keep sop to pring Actions i am not getting ACTION_UP(1) at all if i try to drag the button. So can you please suggest some alternative solution?

Comment: Can you please post it as a new question and provide sufficient details? Your problem may be entirely different.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Thanks for the replay. for me ACTION_UP is not getting called. But its working if i add ACTION_CANCEL. Thanks for the help.